# Pythonanywhere | Selenium Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pythonanywhere

I do it with the same code. Also add no --no-sandbox.
But not working.

I get this one:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591071 (0b695ff80972cc1a65a5cd643186d2ae582cd4ac),platform=Linux 5.4.0-1038-aws x86_64)
```

Comment: Have you tried using another chromium driver? When deploying a selenium crawler/bot on a linux server its probably best to use geckodriver for compatability reasons but i am confident that the chromium driver is capable of running on the pythonanywhere servers, you just need to play around with different driver versions and play around with the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you are getting a crash starting Chrome on PythonAnywhere, it's because you have been leaving processes running by not properly closing the browser in your code. Search for "selenium" on the PythonAnywhere help pages for example code that properly closes Chrome and also shows parameters that you should use.